# Como identificar uma tecla na TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu gostaria de criar um evento que só seria iniciado quando o usuário apertasse "Enter" dentro da TextBox, mas como faço para identificar quando o usuário pressionou essa tecla ?

Comment: Aqui no [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms752054(v=vs.110).aspx) tem um bom exemplo de como fazer.

Comment: É Windows Forms? WPF? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa ativar o **`KeyPreview`** no controle pai do TextBox, é só setar a propriedade pra `true`.

Depois, você precisa usar o evento [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) do TextBox. Este evento é disparado sempre que uma tecla for pressionada no controle e recebe como parâmetro um `KeyEventArgs` (geralmente é chamado de `e`), o `KeyEventArgs` tem uma propriedade chamada `KeyCode` que, por sua vez, é uma [enumeração que contém várias teclas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
     {
         //Fazer algo
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No evento KeyDown do seu Textbox, faça o seguinte :

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
 {
   //executar alguma acao.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando jQuery, independente do navegador, o código para o "Enter" é 13. Então, basta testar se o botão pressionado foi o 13, como segue:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('Você pressionou enter!');
    }
});
```

Comment: **Eu acho** que a pergunta é sobre WinForms...